# jenkins docker pipeline image.withrun do after execute after container healthy

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

After referring this official jenkins docker pipeline official [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#advanced-usage-with-scripted-pipeline), started using the method such as,

```
dockerImage.withRun(){
  ... some scripts ...
}
```

Even i have added the `HEALTHCHECK` command in `Dockerfile`, after building the image and when go for `withRun()` method, the scripts inside `withRun(){ }` executes before the container becomes healthy.

Inside the method, again same healthy check required. It looks some thing strange, so how can i avoid this unwanted step. Or Am i missing some thing ?

**Edit 1 :**

Example Docker file used:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE mydb
ENV MYSQL_USER me
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD password

HEALTHCHECK CMD /usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=password --execute "SHOW DATABASES;"

CMD while true; do sleep 2; done
```

Comment: We likely need to see your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have updated my question with an example `Dockerfile` fyi.